# Followed discussion threads in profile page show with empty title, and in followed page with null user

Tags: bug, status-review, discussions-space, follow-posts

In my profile page, in the section for followed posts, where it displays an entry for a discussion thread (one of the comments under the discussion) I'm following displays the answer icon (is that really a good UI design? I find it overloading and confusing), and no title. And then when I go to the page that displays everything I'm following, the title (of the discussion) is displayed for that entry, and a user picture for [the default user picture](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/user.svg?v=20c64bb67fc9) is displayed. Why display a user picture at all if it's not going to do something that makes sense? Regular posts in the following page don't show user pictures.

Comment: Could add a few Screenshots maybe to make your Post clearer... :idea:

Comment: I find this difficult to follow (no pun intended). Perhaps rephrase?