Timeout on the "Following" page
For a while now (several weeks) I have a strange problem with the page that lists the followed posts in my profile. When I click on the "Following" button in my profile I often get a timeout:

We are currently offline for maintenance.

But sometimes I can visit the first page but get a timeout when I click on the link for page 2.
This morning I was able to access page 1, then clicked on the link for page 2 which did not load. Before the timeout came, I clicked on the link for page 3 which loaded immediately. Then I tried page 2 again and I did not load. So I could only view page 1 and 3, but not 2. But right now I can't access the "Following" pages at all, I get a timeout when I click on the link.
I observe the same behaviour on my PC at home (Firefox, Edge) on my office PC (Firefox) and on my mobile phone (Chrome). I also disable all browser plugins, but that didn't change anything.
Btw. here on Meta I can access the "Following" page (just one page). And as it might be important as well, I have a (too) long list of followed posts (>> 1k), as I'm always too lazy to clean up.
I didn't find a related topic here. Am I the only one with that problem?

This is probably related to a specific followed post. I don't seem to have an issue and I have 10k followed posts. So, it's not a problem with the numbers. The fact that it now seems to happen on page 2 might be because you've followed more posts and now whatever the problematic one is, has moved to page 2.

OK, I did get a timeout on page 5 of my followed posts. But visiting 1-4 and the last few ones does return immediately. For this one I had to wait for a while and in the end it told me "We are currently offline for maintenance". But all other pages on SO and the network work...

Page two is the page where I have all the deleted discussions which I could not unfollow and I wanted to try if it works now as promised. But right now I can't access the page at all, I mean I don't even get the 1st page now. In the morning it was only page two. And "We are currently offline for maintenance" is exactly what I see after a while.

The idea with the specific post sound interesting. Because in the morning it failed on page two, and then, after I unfollowed a couple of posts on page 1 I couln'd access it anymore. So probably due to the unfollowing the bad post moved from page 2 to page 1. But with that theory in mind I followed now a couple of posts to move the bad apple to page two, but that didn't have the desired effect. I'm still getting the timeout on page 1.

Could be something specific that make a post have this issue. And you managed to follow one of those, so it shows on page 1. I still can't get to page 5 but I can get to 6 and others. Easiest when I change page=5 in the URL.

@VLAZ I tried again and it seems your theory is right. After following the 5th post I can finally access page 1 again (bad post moved to page 2). Then I unfollowed a post from page 1 (bad post moved to back to page 1) and immedialty got a timeout when I reloaded. Again followed a new post (bad post moved to page two) and can access page 1. So the first post on page two must be the bad apple in the basket. I guess from here on only a moderator or staff, who hopefully can look into my followed posts, can help to identify the culprit.

Random musing: I wonder if the "Followed posts" widget the profile has the same issue. It only shows 5 followed posts. There is a chance that there is no problem there and it can display the thing which is a problem for the other page. Well, the other alternative is that it'd also kill accessing your Activity tab.

Thank you for reporting this! The "Following" page should now load when following a discussion post.
We have also fixed some discussion related bugs on the "Followed posts" widget visible on the user activity page.

Discussion posts will now show the correct icon.
Replies will no longer show a blank title and instead contain the title of the discussion post prepended with "Reply to".



https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/428079/11107541

OK I scienced around for a bit. My random musing proved correct: you can see the followed items in the Followed posts widget in the Activity tab in the profile. However, opening the Following page in the profile leads to a very long time and an error.

I found out exactly which posts have a problem: Discussions. Specifically, it is the main opening post. Following a reply in a Discussion is fine. Following the main post always leads to an error. Does not matter if it is deleted or not, or anything else, as far as I can see.
In the screenshot, the followed post on the top is a Discussion (yes, labelled as an answer).
You can unfollow the posts from the widget in the profile. Or if you go directly to the post you followed, assuming you know which one it is.

labelled as an answer   ... let me guess the code: if (posttypeid == 1) { icon=Q } else { icon= A}. Luckily we can't follow wikis or excerpts or moderator nominations ...

@VLAZ perfect, I tried and it works exactly as you described!

The widget only shows 5 followed posts and no matter which sorting I choose, I can never show and unfollow the old followed discussions from 6 month ago, unless I just unfollow evrything from the last 6 month via the widget.

@jps yeah, I unfollowed 5 full pages of posts to get the one that didn't work to show on top... It's definitely not a great solution. I then re-followed the 5 full pages (30 posts per page). I can describe this experience as "not super pleasant".

@rene or articles

@VLAZ not super pleasant - it seems almost every aspect of "discussions" can be described with that. Maybe just one more reason to turn it off!
